# Is there a name for property $n+k=m+k\implies n=m$?

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers, monoid

Monoid of natural numbers with addition have such property, that for any $n,m, k \in \mathbb{N}$ if $n+k=m+k$ then $n=m$. Does this property have some name in English?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually see it being called the [cancellation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property). (because what you are doing above is *cancelling* the $k$s in both sides).

More precisely, as has been pointed out in the comment below, this is the *right* cancellation property.

Comment: Right cancellation, to be precise.

Comment: Or "right cancellability"

Answer (score 2):

This is the cancellation property. Bear in mind that it does not hold for a general monoid. The cancellative property is guaranteed by the existence of inverses, therefore, all monoids with inverses (groups) are cancellation structures.

Comment: You must mean that all *monoids* with inverses are cancellation structures.  This is because for $mk = nk$ to imply $m = n$, you need to write $(mk)k^{-1} = m(k k^{-1})$, i.e. you need associativity.  For an explicit magma counterexample, take $\{e, x, y\}$ with identity $e$, $x^2 = y^2 = xy = yx = e$.  In this example $x$ has inverse $x$ and $y$ has inverse $y$, and $xy = yy$, but $x \ne y$.

Comment: @Goos, no, I didn't mean that, I was just wrong :P. Yes, we also need associativity. I'll update.

Comment: @Goos but in your example we have $x=xe=x(xy)=x^2y=y$

Comment: @Michael Goos is giving a counter-example of a general magma with inverses being cancellative, you are assuming associativity.

Comment: @MichalSeweryn $x(xy) \ne (x^2) y$.  Magma's [don't need to be associative](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/779507/can-you-give-me-some-concrete-examples-of-magmas).